# How do I create new columns with pandas by combining rows with a particular value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with two "categories" of information. One category is repeated across multiple rows, and the other is specific to each row.

It looks something like this:

```
City State Industry Pay Hours
15   10    1        20  40
15   10    2        30  25
20   10    1        25  30
20   10    2        50  80
```

I want it to look like:

```
City State Industry1Pay Industry1Hours Industry2Pay Industry2Hours
15   10    20           40             30           25
20   10    25           30             50           80
```

This is a simplified version because the full table is much too long to fit up there. There are 8 columns in place of city and state, and 2 additional columns to pay and hours. In addition, each row should contain 4 industries for now (it will be 5 once that data comes in).

I am really struggling with how to do this. The dataset is from a project conducted in Stata, so the columns are mostly floats and need to stay that way for when I send it in.

The closest I think I've gotten is

```
wage = wage.pivot_table(index='cityid', columns='Industry').rename_axis(None)
wage.columns = wage.columns.map('_'.join)
```

but I get an error because you can't join a float to a string, and I suspect that this will not work the way I'm hoping it will regardless.

So far I've looked at quite a few stackoverflow questions, as well as:
https://hackernoon.com/reshaping-data-in-python-fa27dda2ff77
http://nikgrozev.com/2015/07/01/reshaping-in-pandas-pivot-pivot-table-stack-and-unstack-explained-with-pictures/
and two others I am unable to link to because I haven't used stackoverflow very much

I'm really struggling with this, and would appreciate any help, even a link to a good tutorial to wrap my head around this. It seems like a really simple task but for the life of me I can't figure out how to do it without just manually moving stuff around in Excel.

I apologize in advance if this is a duplicate - I looked around a lot but I might be missing something obvious because I'm not sure what this is called beyond reshaping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's use `set_index` and `unstack`:

```
df['Industry'] = 'Industry'+df.Industry.astype(str)
df_out = df.set_index(['City','State','Industry']).unstack()
```

And flatten the multiindex columns with `swaplevel`, `map`, `join`:

```
df_out.columns = df_out.columns.swaplevel(1,0)
df_out.columns = df_out.columns.map(''.join)
```

Output:

```
            Industry1Pay  Industry2Pay  Industry1Hours  Industry2Hours
City State                                                            
15   10               20            30              40              25
20   10               25            50              30              80
```

## In case of multiple values of City, State, and Industry then use `pivot_table`

```
df['Industry'] = 'Industry'+df.Industry.astype(str)

df_out = df.pivot_table(index=['City','State'],columns='Industry',values=['Pay','Hours'], aggfunc='sum')

df_out.columns = df_out.columns.swaplevel(1,0)
df_out.columns = df_out.columns.map(''.join)

df_out
```

## OR use groupby

```
df_out = df.groupby(['City','State','Industry'])['Pay','Hours'].sum().unstack()

df_out.columns = df_out.columns.swaplevel(1,0)
df_out.columns = df_out.columns.map(''.join)
df_out
```

Output:

```
            Industry1Pay  Industry2Pay  Industry1Hours  Industry2Hours
City State                                                            
15   10               20            30              40              25
20   10               25            50              30              80
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time! To get this working, I had to change the df_out to `df_out = df.set_index(['City', 'State', 'Industry'], append=True).unstack` as another StackOverflow question recommended. I am now getting the error `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found`. I believe this to be the result of the Industry column being a float, but I was unable to figure out how to change this to a string for the map join section.

Comment: Jackson, you shouldn't need the apend=True, this is causing the problem with the map join statement.  Can you remove append=True and let me know the error.

Comment: Scott, when I remove the apend=True, I get the error `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape` but I do not think that I have entirely duplicate entries, just the scenario I laid out where City and State will be duplicated. I looked through the data and could not find any duplicate rows without variation.

Comment: @JacksonLuckey Sorry, i missed the duplicated city, state, industry values.   Use pivot_table or groupby which provide a means to aggregate duplicate entries.  See edited answer.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for looking for. It even produces nice looking column names.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to use pivot

```
In [38]: df.pivot_table(index=['City', 'State'],
                        columns='Industry', 
                        values=['Pay', 'Hours'])
Out[38]:
           Pay     Hours
Industry     1   2     1   2
City State
15   10     20  30    40  25
20   10     25  50    30  80
```

To flatten the pivot and add column names.

```
In [94]: dff = df.pivot_table(index=['City', 'State'], columns='Industry',
                              values=['Pay', 'Hours'])

In [95]: cols = ['Industry%s%s' % x for x in zip(dff.columns.get_level_values(1), 
                                                 dff.columns.get_level_values(0))]

In [96]: cols
Out[96]: ['Industry1Pay', 'Industry2Pay', 'Industry1Hours', 'Industry2Hours']

In [97]: dff.columns = cols

In [98]: dff.reset_index()
Out[98]:
   City  State  Industry1Pay  Industry2Pay  Industry1Hours  Industry2Hours
0    15     10            20            30              40              25
1    20     10            25            50              30              80
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm getting an error 'IndexError: Too many levels: Index has only 1 level, not 2' for the line that generates the columns. I have 4 to 5 industries per row I want to create. Is that what is causing the error? I tried adding additional 'get_level_values()' to match the number of industries, but that did not help.